# How to create ground truth for the map from ROS

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I am new to ROS and I am using Octomap to create a 3D map of a lab. I would like to know how to create ground truth for the map from ROS and how to compare the map that I produce using Octomap with the ground truth.

- How to get ground truth for a 3D map
- How to compare 3D map produced from Octomap to ground truth

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386201/how-to-create-ground-truth-for-the-map-from-ros/) by [Bigby](https://answers.ros.org/users/84331/bigby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could make a CAD model of the lab (using something like Solidworks, Fusion 360, or TinkerCAD) and output it as a .stl or COLLADA file (.dae), then [display that model in rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D) as a mesh resource.

You'll need to figure out the details of lining up the coordinate systems of your ground truth model and the map you're making, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2021-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1